# Are there any plugins to 'star' messages in Mail.app?

Tags: macos, mac, email, gmail, apple-mail

I am a gmail user and sync up via IMAP with Mail.app.

I want to be able to "star" messages.

Is there a plugin available to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality is already basically there; if you're using mail.app to connect to Gmail, "flagging" a mail item in mail.app will cause it to be "starred" in gmail.